# Quarkus devservices not starting config free postgres db

Tags: postgresql, quarkus

I just wanted to try dev services for spinning up a config free postgres in docker as I read at https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#dev-services-configuration-free-databases

Generated a quarkus project https://code.quarkus.io/ with dependency `quarkus-jdbc-postgresql`
and application.properties looks like

```
quarkus.datasource.devservices.enabled=true
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.devservices.port=5432
```

Starting quarkus does NOT spin up postgres, instead I get a warning that quarkus does not understand its own properties, see Quarkus Log

```
2022-03-09 23:11:14,433 WARN  [io.qua.config] (Quarkus Main Thread) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.datasource.devservices.enabled" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
2022-03-09 23:11:14,433 WARN  [io.qua.config] (Quarkus Main Thread) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.datasource.devservices.port" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
2022-03-09 23:11:14,433 WARN  [io.qua.config] (Quarkus Main Thread) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.datasource.db-kind" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
2022-03-09 23:11:14,936 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) quarkus-resteasy-postgres 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.7.4.Final) started in 2.182s. Listening on: http://localhost:8080
2022-03-09 23:11:14,937 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2022-03-09 23:11:14,937 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [cdi, jdbc-postgresql, resteasy, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Project here: https://github.com/syr/quarkus-resteasy-postgres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your warning message, there's one extension missing for this configuration:

```sh
2022-03-09 23:11:14,433 WARN  [io.qua.config] (Quarkus Main Thread) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.datasource.db-kind" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
```

You can solve your problem adding one of these dependencies to your project (on your pom.xml):

### Pool your database connections (included in Hibernate ORM)

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

or

### Hibernate ORM

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Actually, OP is likely missing the Postgresql extension

Comment: @geoand , I saw that he had the ```<dependency><groupId>io.quarkus</groupId><artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId></dependency>``` dependency on his project. I tested and I only could fix the problem adding one of the above dependencies. Am misunderstanding something? It's here https://github.com/syr/quarkus-resteasy-postgres/blob/main/pom.xml

Comment: @FelipeWindmoller Good, after adding quarkus-agroal, dev services are spinning up postgres. However, I am still confused that I did not see anything about this in the quarkus docs. Furthermore, I wonder how to define username, password and how to mount to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/* which would have to be done in the dockerfile.
Defined `quarkus.datasource.username`, `quarkus.datasource.password` in application.properties but credentials are denied.

Comment: The username and password were correctly configured as expected.. I was just misreading the error of my db Client which was configured to a non existing schema. That's why I marked the answer als solution.